# Zip files with password with ZipArchive Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a problem while zipping a password protected file using ZipArchive Objective-C library.
My code is the following:

```
ZipArchive * zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zip CreateZipFile2: nameOfZip Password: @"hello"];

for (int i = 0; i < [dirContents count]; i++) {
    NSString * pathToFile = @"the path...";

    [zip addFileToZip: percorsoFile newname: @"the name of the file"];
}

[zip CloseZipFile2];
```

The zip file is successfully created but the problem is that when I try to extract it on my Mac using the default program, it always says 'Password incorrect'.
Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: There are at least ten different encryption standards listed in the [ZIP standard](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).  The odds are pretty good that the two sides aren't agreeing on the standard used.

Comment: And how can I know (or change) the encryption used by ZipArchive?

Comment: Read the standard.  There's supposed to be a header generated that tells you which algorithm was used.  (Though there's no guarantee that ZipArchive observes the standard.)

Answer (score 0):

you create the produced file with "hello" password. Those file want to unzip use following code.

```
[zip UnzipOpenFile:nameOfZip Password:@"hello"];
```

Comment: The OP wants to unzip the file using the default Archive Utility, not unzip it himself.

Comment: I agree with TheAmateurProgrammer